# How do I mock a property on a Scala companion object using Mockito and ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest

I have a simple companion Object that is creating a connection pool that should be globally static.

```
object CoreDataSource {
  val pool : DataSource = getDataSource
  def getDataSource: DataSource = {
    ...
  }
}
```

I then use that in a variety of classes like...

```
class Query {
  var source: DataSource = CoreDataSource.pool
  def getSalutations: String = {
    val conn : Connection = source.getConnection
    ...
  }
}
```

Now I would like to test the `getSalutations` without the `getDataSource` actually getting called. Is there a way to mock out this call so that when the initial `getDataSource` call happens it hits a mock instead of the actual function?

Here is the skeleton of my test suite...

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MySuite extends AnyFunSuite with MockitoSugar {
  test("Test mocking the Datasource") {
    // Mock object here
  }
}
```

I Also tried...

```
var pool : Option[DataSource] = None
  def getConnection: Connection = {
    if(pool.isEmpty)
      pool = getDataSource
    pool.get.getConnection
  }
  def getDataSource: Option[DataSource] = {
    ...
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MySuite extends AnyFunSuite with MockitoSugar with Matchers {
  test("Test mocking the Datasource") {
    withObjectMocked[CoreDataSource.type]{
      val source = mock[DataSource]
      when(CoreDataSource.getDataSource).thenReturn(Some(source))
      ...
      assert(result == "")
    }
  }
}
```

But this throws

```
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
  - final class
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to accept my workaround because it is ugly but this ended up working...

```scala
class CoreDataSource {
  def getConnection = {
    CoreDataSource.getConnection
  }
}
object CoreDataSource {
  var pool : Option[DataSource] = None
  def getConnection: Connection = {
    if(pool.isEmpty)
      pool = getDataSource
    pool.get.getConnection
  }
  def getDataSource: Option[DataSource] = {
    ...
  }
}
class Query(ds: CoreDataSource = new CoreDataSource) {
  def getSalutations: String = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then the following will work...

```scala
  test("Single record returned") {
    val cds = mock[CoreDataSource]
    val source = mock[Connection]
    doNothing.when(source).close()
    when(cds.getConnection).thenReturn(source)
    val q = new Query(cds)
    val result = q.getSalutations
    assert(result == "This is the test value")
  }
```